# SHA function issues

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have this php code from my login.php

```
if (isset($_POST['logIn'])) {
    $errmsg = "";
    $logname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['usernameIn']));
    $logpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['passwordIn']));

    $query = "SELECT user_id, username FROM members WHERE username = '$logname' AND password = SHA('$logpassword')";
    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
        setcookie('user_id', $row['user_id'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30)); //expires after 30 days
        setcookie('username', $row['username'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30));
        $home = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/index.php';
        header('Location: ' . $home);
    }
    else {
        $errmsg = '<p class="errormsg">Username or password is incorrect.</p>';
    }
}
```

And for some reason, it always ends up setting $errmsg in the else statement. I am sure that I'm entering information (username,password) that is correct and exists in the database.

I insert my values (from a signup script) using this query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO members (username, password, email) VALUES ('$username', SHA('$password'), '$email')";
```

Anyone see the problem with this script? Thanks!

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability where you concatenate the input to the query string.  Do a quick search on SO for PHP and SQL Injection and you should find how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't notice any significant errors in your code but I have a number of suggestions to help debug it:

1. Check the username and password again.  echo both of these out right before the query to ensure they still match what's in the database after they are escaped.
2. echo the query string and run it in phpmyadmin or a shell.
3. Make sure the values are being sent as a POST and not a GET.
4. Change `if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) {` to `if (mysqli_num_rows($data) > 0) {` in case two rows have the same username and password

Comment: "... in case two rows have the same username and password" -- I'd consider this a failure, not a success.  The table should not be designed to permit such a bizarre thing.

Comment: agreed. but it would still help in debugging the current problem

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it from PHP with:

```
VALUES ('$username', '".sha1($password)."', '$email')";
```

In that situation you don't need to use escape it.

Comment: Did you try to see if anything is returned in $data?
I usually "sha" the passwords inside PHP. As they return the same, technically the error must be elsewhere. I don't see so far anything wrong with your code. Check if the DB is connected.